# Discussion: Chat server via node.js: HTTP or TCP?

Tags: http, node.js, tcp, websocket, socket.io

I was considering doing a chat server using node.js/socket.io.  Should I make it a tcp server or a http server?  I'd imagine tcp server would be more efficient, but can you send other stuff to it like file attachments etc?  If tcp is more efficient, how much more so?  Also, just wondering how many concurrent connections can one node.js server handle?  Is it more work to do TCP or HTTP?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are talking about 2 totally different approaches here - TCP is a transport layer protocol and HTTP is an application layer protocol. HTTP (usually) operates over TCP, so whichever option you choose, it will still be operating over TCP.

The efficiency question is sort of a moot point, because you are talking about different [OSI layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). If you went for raw TCP sockets, your solution would probably be more efficient - in bandwidth at least - since HTTP contains a whole bunch of extra data (the headers) that would likely be irrelevant to your purposes (depending on the scale of the chat program). What you are talking about developing there is your own application layer protocol.

You can send anything you like over TCP - after all HTTP can send attachments, and that operates over TCP. FTP also operates over TCP, and that is designed purely for transferring "attachments". In order to do this, you would need to write your protocol so that it was able to tell the remote party that the following data was a file, then send the file data, then tell the remote party that the transfer is complete. Implementations of this are many and varied (the HTTP approach is completely different from the FTP approach) and your options are pretty much infinite.

I don't know for sure about the node.js connection limit, but I can say with a fair amount of confidence that it is limited by the operating system. [This](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/e59676e9b3567ce4) might help you get to grips with the answer to that question.

It is debatable whether it is more work to do it with TCP or HTTP - it's a lot of work to do it in both. I would probably lean more toward the TCP option being your best bet. While TCP would require you to design a protocol rather than/as well as an application, HTTP is not particularly suited to live, 2-way applications like chat servers. There are many implementations of chat over HTTP that use AJAX, but I can tell you from painful experience that they are a complete pain in the rear-end.

I would say that you should only be looking at HTTP if you are intending the endpoint (i.e. the client) to be a browser. If you are going to write a desktop app for the endpoint, a direct TCP link would definitely be the way to go. The main reason for this is that HTTP works in a request-response manner, where the client sends a request to the server, and the server responds. Over TCP you can open a single TCP stream, that can be used for bi-directional communication. This means that the server can push an event to the client instantly, while over HTTP you have to wait for the client to send a request, so you can respond with an event. If you were intending to use a browser as the client, it will make the whole file transfer thing much more tricky (the sending at least).

There are ways to implement this over HTTP using long-polling and server push ([read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)) but it can be a real pain to implement.

If you are going to implement this on a LAN (or possibly even over the internet) it is worth considering UDP over TCP - in a chat application it is not usually absolutely mission critical that messages arrive in the right order, and even if it was, users would probably not be able to type faster than the variations in network latency (probably <100ms). Then for file transfers you could either negotiate a seperate TCP socket for the data exchange (like FTP), or implement some kind of UDP ACK system (like TFTP).

I feel there is a lot more to say on this subject but right now I can't put it into words - I may extend this answer at some point.

Comment: do you have any idea how to do tcp with node.js/socket.io client side?  I have this question listed here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340475/client-side-tcp-with-node-js-socket-io

Comment: btw. thanks for explaining a lot. its helping a lot.  However, can you explain more about udp and its advantages/disadvantages over tcp? thanks so much!

Comment: does udp packet loss affect a chat app?

Comment: Packet loss could potentially affect the app, and this would be worse over UDP, since the other end does not know the packet has been lost. It depends where you intend to deploy - in a LAN scenario you don't really need to worry about it, over the internet it's more of an issue.

Comment: The main advantages of UDP over TCP are: smaller packet size, less traffic in general because there is no SEQ/ACK, and the ability to [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast)/[broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address). Main disadvantage is that if you're losing packets, you'll never know about it, unless you design your own sequencing system. TFTP operates over UDP and provides it's own sequencing system to make sure the other end puts the data back together in the correct order, and still uses less bandwidth than FTP (TCP), but not recommended across the internet.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not so hot specifically with node.js - I'm not bad with javascript and it's something I've been meaning to play around with for a while, but never actually got round to it. The above information is really more about the general relationship between TCP and HTTP, which applies no matter what language you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Chat servers are the Hello World program in node. Use http.

As far as the question of how many concurrent connections can it handle, that all depends on your system. Set up a simple chat server and then try benchmarking it.

Also, check out http://search.npmjs.org/ and search for `chat` for a few pointers.